# Appimage make package issue

Tags: ruby, linux, appimage

I need to release my program which wrote in ruby. 
first of all I would like to make ruby to appimage package to client linux.
now I make the "ruby-img" folder and put the desktop file down looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Development;
Icon=ruby
Name=ruby
Type=Application
Exec=ruby
```

the ruby what I use was compiled --prefix to "/app" folder, the folder is "/app/ruby" that contains "/app/ruby/bin, /app/ruby/lib ..." and then I copied /app/ruby entire folder to "ruby-img" folder, it looks like "ruby-img/app/ruby, ruby-img/usr ..." then I make the symbol link as "ln -r -s app/ruby/bin/ruby usr/bin/." in "ruby-img" folder.
and using appimagetools to create ruby-x86-64.AppImage. but can not run. some ruby lib can not found, (it looks like running ruby.AppImage, ruby lib path still find in /app/ruby/lib, but not in "ruby-img/app/ruby/lib", if i renamed /app/ruby it will occurs error)

i have tried recompile ruby --prefix to /usr/local/ruby or /tmp/ruby ... then copy to "ruby-img" and make some relative things, fix desktop file, but still can't run ruby.AppImage what appimagetool created.

any idea can help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you ran into the same problem as I did. Check https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/1004#issuecomment-1018423834